# Get hold of the component ID that has triggered a submit in Java

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In Xpages I can use $$xspsubmitid in SSJS to check which component has initiated a submit.

> $$xspsubmitid = Is loaded with the Event handler ID of what event you
>   want to execute.

Is something similar available in java?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The *$$xspsubmitid* is stored in the request parameter map:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("$$xspsubmitid");
```

**EDIT:**

The id of the refreshed element is **always** stored in *$$ajaxid*. And in *$$xspsubmitid* you will always find the id of the event which has started the refresh. But you have to look at your event handler if there is a id defined. If not, XPages creates an id automatically.

Comment: Hello Sven, I think you might be right, but with a partial refresh I get the id of the element that is partially refreshed.